# Trying to link a anchor tag to a div id in meteor js

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, scroll, meteor

For some reason I cant seem to get my anchor tag to link to a div id lower down in the page. Heres a [link](http://iclinic.meteor.com/) to the broken site, try and click on How it works and minimize your window to allow for the scroll to happen, it doesn't scroll down the page and I'm not sure why. I am trying to solve this now with javascript (specifically jQuery and meteors template events) I think meteor was preventing to classic way of doing this from working, but Im still stuck.

***I am using meteor so I think this might be my problem, I am trying a different solution now, but it is not working***

JS

```
Template.postsList.events({
  'click #worksClick':function(e,tmpl) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#works").offset().top
      }, 600);
   }
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="postsList">

<div class="container">

  <div class="logo">
    <h1>iClinic</h1>
  </div>

  <nav class="topNav">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="worksClick" href="#works">How it works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Reach Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="mastHead">
    <header>
      <h2>iClinic helps the medical professional bring superior health-care to all people</h2>
    </header>
  </div><!--mastHead ends-->

  <div class="detailsWrapper">

    <section class="details">
      <h3>The more you know the better you can treat.</h3>
    </section>

  </div>

  <div id="works" class="worksWrapper">

    <section class="works">
      <h3>How it Works</h3>
      <p>iClinic runs on any web browser or Windows computer, you simply create a account and begin to intergrate your existing and new patient data into iClinic</p>
    </section>

  </div>


  <div id="workas" class="worksWrapper">

    <section class="works">
      <h3>How it Works</h3>
      <p>iClinic runs on any web browser or Windows computer, you simply create a account and begin to intergrate your existing and new patient data into iClinic</p>
    </section>

  </div>

</div><!--container ends-->

</template>
```

[STYLUS](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) (which complies to css this is not incorrectly written css)

```
*
  margin 0
  padding 0

.container
  width 100%

.adminNav
  display none

html
  font-size 90%
  font-family 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif

.logo
  float left
  background #7d7d7d
  width 15%
  padding 3rem 0 3rem 0
  //padding-top 3.5rem
  h1
    font-size 4rem
    font-weight 100
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem
    text-align center
    color #fff


.topNav
  float left
  width 85%
  padding 4.7rem 0 3.8rem 0
  background #d3d3d3
  ul
    li
      display inline
      font-size 2rem
      font-weight 100
      a
        margin-left 3rem
        text-decoration none
        color #fff

.mastHead
  background #989797 url("http://www.proteus.com/assets/helius_professional_header2.jpg")
  background-size cover
  background-position 0 -5rem
  background-repeat no-repeat
  background-attachment fixed
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);s
  width 100%
  clear left

header
  width 66%
  margin auto
  padding-top 5rem
  padding-bottom 5rem
  h2
    font-size 4rem
    font-weight 500
    letter-spacing 0.2rem
    text-align center
    color #fff
    text-shadow 2px 2px 2px #000

@media(min-width:1400px)
  header
    width 50%
    padding-top 20rem
    padding-bottom 20rem

.detailsWrapper
  width 100%
  background #989797
  float left

.details
  width 66%
  margin auto
  text-align center
  padding 5rem 0 5rem 0

  h3

    font-size 3rem
    font-weight 100
    color #fff
    letter-spacing 0.3rem

.worksWrapper
  width 100%
  float left
  background rgba(155, 154, 154, 0.18)

.works
  width 66%
  margin auto
  text-align center
  padding 5rem 0 5rem 0

  h3

    font-size 3rem
    font-weight 100
    color #fff
    letter-spacing 0.3rem
```

COMPILED CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

.container {
    width: 100%
}

.adminNav {
    display: none
}

html {
    font-size: 90%;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    background: #7d7d7d;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 3rem 0 3rem 0
}

.logo h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff
}

.topNav {
    float: left;
    width: 85%;
    padding: 4.7rem 0 3.8rem 0;
    background: #d3d3d3
}

.topNav ul li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 100
}

.topNav ul li a {
    margin-left: 3rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff
}

.mastHead {
    background: #989797 url("http://www.proteus.com/assets/helius_professional_header2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 -5rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    width: 100%;
    clear: left
}

header {
    width: 66%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem
}

header h2 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
    header {
        width:50%;
        padding-top: 20rem;
        padding-bottom: 20rem
    }
}

.detailsWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: #989797;
    float: left
}

.details {
    width: 66%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5rem 0 5rem 0
}

.details h3 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.3rem
}

.worksWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: rgba(155,154,154,0.18)
}

.works {
    width: 66%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5rem 0 5rem 0
}

.works h3 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.3rem
}
```

Comment: Appears to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CR76J/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THIS ENDED UP WORKING FOR ME BELOW.

```
 Template.postsList.events({
    'click #worksClick': function (evt) {
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#works").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A Javascript listener blocks this. Any `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false` bound on a element you click on (body, divs, ...). Your page works fine with Javascript disabled, please check all your code or show us your JS.

Comment: I think this has to with Meteor which is what I am using, there is a lot of javascript files so Im not even sure which ones would be causing this, i think its something built into meteor, I added some code that was recommended to do this but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags not working in Meteor is a [known issue](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/248). Here's an easy fix:

```
# Create link to anchor
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'postsList' hash='works'}}">How it works</a></li>

# Set anchor
<div id="works"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick improvement on previous answers for anyone that finds this post. Here was the solution that seemed to work for me:

```js
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    if(window.location.hash) {
      let checkContent = $(window.location.hash).length;
      if(checkContent > 0){
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
          scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
        }, 1000);
      }else{
        window.setTimeout(function(){
          let checkContent = $(window.location.hash).length;
          if(checkContent > 0){
            $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
              scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
            }, 1000);
          }
        }, 300);
      }
    }
  }, 300);
```

Just throw that into your onRendered function and it should cover most use cases. It checks for the # element, waits 300ms for things to render, and then smooth scrolls. If the element does not exist after 300ms it waits another 300ms and then tries again.

I know its still not 100% optimal, but its a bit more defensive than past solutions I have found.

HOPE THIS HELPS SOMEONE! :)

Answer (score -4):

You have a variable called `workas`, not sure if this is supposed to be works.

Comment: It has been forever since I looked at this code, I don't even have the repo stored somewhere, but I think that `id` was intentional.

Comment: I think this answer is more suitable as a comment